# Add column to all database tables as predefined and append it as index to all indexes to be defined?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, prisma

Currently I'm implementing a multi-tenant solution using single shared database by defining A tenant column in each database table.
I'm thinking of automating this process by adding a tenant column by default to each and every table on creation, and add the tenant as index composite with any defined index in the table.

Using Prisma and postgres, I tried to create a custom generator and adjust the `options.dmmf.datamodel` models, and I was thinking to overwrite the current schema with the new one. But somehow I can't generate a schema from `options.dmmf.datamodel`.

So, is there a function to convert `options.dmmf.datamodel` to string?
**Is this even the right way to do so?**

Another Solution would be create an event trigger ON CREATE and create that column, but this will make prisma migration out of sync with database!

Comment: Perhaps that is trying to automate too much, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

For now, you would need to manually add the tenant column in new tables.

There's a Feature Request: [#2506](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/2506) for adding support for Inheritance which would allow you to inherit the tenant column in every table.